# Checking for hasChild in heap

Tags: java

Let's say I want to check whether an index in the heap has a child. This heap implementation is in array form in Java.

In my `boolean hasChild` function, I was thinking of checking it with `if(index < currentSize/2)`, where currentSize is the size of the array used to implement the heap.

Does this cover for the case where the root is at index 0 or 1? I find it hard to visualise it. If it's the former, how do I implement for the latter? Or vice versa.

Will edit the post if there is anything unclear.

(Sorry but I need 2k rep to accept edits)

Comment: The Java heap does not have indexes available to the programmer so if this is Java (like it was originally tagged) we really have no idea what you're asking. If it's some other language please tell us what it is. It's also unclear what you mean by "child".

Comment: @Radiodef Ok, will change the tag back to Java because that is how it's implemented. I was confused why someone suggested to change it to 'algorithm' instead... And aren't heaps implemented using arrays usually?

Comment: I think that Radiodef is confusing the java memory model heap with what I presume that you are talking about: an implementation of the heap data structure in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming min heap. Indexing always starts at 1 by convention. This is so that the position formula can be consistent even for the first element. Using this convention direct children are always at 2k and 2k+1. So for childs not to exist 2k must be > kmax.

2k > kmax

k > kmax/2

If you are using an array where element 0 is empty kmax is actually array size - 1. If you are using an array with index offset it's just array size. So the actual formula for your implementation is dependent of your definitions of index and maxSize. But your formula basically seems correct if you are building a max heap.

Answer (score 0):

the root can't never bee 0 . since the index of the left son is 2n and the right son is 2n+1 , where n is the current index. And 0 is neutral to multiplication .

if you implement a heap with an array..the following predicate should be sufficient  :

(2*idx <= arr.size && arr[2*idx] !=null) && (2*idx+1<= arr.size && arr[2*idx+1] !=null)

'<=' since you count from 1 and not from 0 as always ..

check this reference for heap's : 
http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~ds132/wiki.files/ds132_ps9_updated.pdf